# Add click listeners to a multiple imageButtons inside a gridLayout - Android Studio

Tags: java, android, xml, android-layout

I'm building a app that have a grid of imageButtons inside of it, I'm setting it from a method, here's the code:

```
public class BoardLoader {
public void createEmptyGrid(Context context, GridLayout gridLayout, Image image) {
    LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    int counter = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < image.getWidth(); i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < image.getHeight(); j++) {
            
            View pixelView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.pixel_item_no_tint, gridLayout, false);

            GridLayout.Spec rowSpec = GridLayout.spec(i);
            GridLayout.Spec colSpec = GridLayout.spec(j);
            GridLayout.LayoutParams params = new GridLayout.LayoutParams(rowSpec, colSpec);

            pixelView.setId(counter);
            counter++;

            pixelView.setLayoutParams(params);
            gridLayout.addView(pixelView);
        }
    }
}
```

}

The grid is showing correctly, so the next step is to add event listener to all of the imageButtons, I don't want to do it one by one, instead using a method, this is the one that I think might work:

```
private void setGridListeners(GridLayout gridLayout) {

    for (int i = 0; i < gridLayout.getChildCount(); i++) {
        View pixelView = gridLayout.getChildAt(i);
        pixelView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Log.e("testing", "hope it works");
            }
        });
    }
}
```

But when I see in Logcat is not showing the log, I try in many ways to achieve the goal, like use tags instead of id's, add the listeners inside the createEmptyGrid method, even try with another imageButton outside to verify that was not error of the method, etc... But none of them works

Here's how it looks, the buttons show feedback so is not error of buttons not working or not receiving the click

[image: error in grid]

If someone figure out what's happening will help me so much

Thanks in advance

Steven

UPDATE: Here's the mainActivity content:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private GridLayout gridLayout;
private ImageAdapter imageAdapter;

private BoardLoader boardLoader;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


    imageAdapter = new ImageAdapter();
    boardLoader = new BoardLoader();


    Controller control = new Controller();
    control.imagesList(this);

    int n = control.imagesList(this).get(0).getHeight();


    gridLayout = findViewById(R.id.gridLayout);
    gridLayout.setRowCount(n);
    gridLayout.setColumnCount(n);

    imageAdapter.createReferenceImage(this, gridLayout, control.imagesList(this).get(0));
    boardLoader.createEmptyGrid(this, gridLayout, control.imagesList(this).get(0));
    setGridListeners(gridLayout);
}

private void setGridListeners(GridLayout gridLayout) {

    for (int i = 0; i < gridLayout.getChildCount(); i++) {
        View pixelView = gridLayout.getChildAt(i);
        pixelView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Log.e("testing", "hope it works");
            }
        });
    }
}
```

}

Comment: What is output of `gridLayout.getChildCount()`?

Comment: @DinhLam it returns the amount of elements inside the grid, so it's actually adding the imageButtons, in the specific case returns 64

Comment: where are u call `setGridListeners`? maybe the click listener was removed in somewhere.

Comment: The method is inside the main activity, and is called in the oncreate method, something like this:

        gridLayout = findViewById(R.id.gridLayout);
        gridLayout.setRowCount(n);
        gridLayout.setColumnCount(n);

        boardLoader.createEmptyGrid(this, gridLayout, control.imagesList(this).get(0));

Comment: can u post main activity's code to this post or attach the github link? i need more info to figure out the problem.

Comment: Sure, I'll edit the post and add the mainActivity code for you to see

Comment: @StevenLeón Can you try to set pixelView.clickable = true before setting click listener once and see if it effects something.

Comment: @AndroidKiller I tried to add it as you told me, before adding the event listener and also when the imageButtons are created and doesn't affect, anyway thank you

Comment: @StevenLeón Can you add the tag while creating and printing tag while adding listers, if they are printing the same value. Just wanted to make sure we are adding listeners to same view.

Comment: @AndroidKiller Sorry for the late answer, I tried to add the clickable and also a tag when creating and print it there and also when event listeners are added and are the same, print the same value, first the list of the tags when added and then after the event listeners are supposed to be added :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I figured out how to solve the problem and I'll post here my solution if is helpful for someone.

Basically was a bunch of "beginner" mistakes, and I will list them:

**1. Inflating incorrect layout (or, in other words, layout was wrong)**

So, I use to have my ImageButtons inside a constraintLayout (Cause I was not knowing how to position it correctly), so that was the first mistake, cause when I was doing this:

```
 View pixelView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.pixel_item_no_tint, gridLayout, false);
```

I was inflating the constraintLayout, not the imageButton, that's why I wasn't able to add the event listeners, I verify that making a validation and logging the class type of the pixelView:

```
Log.e("View Class", "Class of pixelView: " + pixelView.getClass().getName());

if (pixelView instanceof ImageButton) {
    Log.e("Testing", "" + pixelView.getTag());
}
```

Then for solve the problem I delete the constraintLayout of the ImageButton and it starts adding the event listeners, however other problem comes:

**2. Not setting the width and height GridLayout Params inside the code**

So, after I figured out what was happening I stop seeing my buttons on the screen, after a lot of debugging I found that the problem was that the imageButtons wasn't taking the atributes of width and height, even when I have them inside my xml, like this:

```
android:layout_width="35dp"
android:layout_height="35dp"
```

So after a lot of attempts I figured out that I have to specify that property inside the params of the imageButton inside the gridLayout (when been added), like this:

```
            GridLayout.Spec rowSpec = GridLayout.spec(i);
            GridLayout.Spec colSpec = GridLayout.spec(j);
            GridLayout.LayoutParams params = new GridLayout.LayoutParams(rowSpec, colSpec);
            params.width = 50;
            params.height = 50;

            pixelView.setId(counter);
            pixelView.setClickable(true);

            pixelView.setLayoutParams(params);
```

And with that I was able to see the gridLayout and test that the eventListeners are working correctly, then you can change each imageButton width and height inside of it programmatically. Hope it help someone, thanks for the persons who comment the post too.